# Prevent proxy reassignment

Tags: windows, windows-7, internet-explorer-8, gpo

I work in big company and big brother always watching and enforce its own rules. However to do my job I have special proxy server settings in IE8 which gives me access to what I need. All legal and based on job description. Everything is fine except every few hours my settings go back to standard and I have to reset them manually to this special proxy. I think security team forces some GPO settings which do this. I have admin rights on my computer but, of course, no rights on the domain. Is there way for me to prevent such changes in my personal settings?

That would be very helpful. Even I can do changes manually it most bothers me when I have automated processes. Some batch runs in the middle of the night and it can't work because proxy settings are wrong. Very frustrating.

Any help?

Comment: Did you try to change registry values manually or in this batch process?

Comment: Yes, I tried. But it may happen that proxy changes came in the middle of the batch process and so it dies.

Comment: You can probably prevent the group policy engine from changing the relevant registry settings by changing the ACLs (security permissions) to grant only read access.  I'm not sure where those settings live, but I expect it's documented.  You might also consider running IE inside a self-administered (i.e., not part of the domain) virtual machine - that would have the advantage of allowing you to only use the special proxy settings for those tasks that need it, rather than all the time.  (But check whether you have a valid Windows license for the prospective VM first.)

Comment: It actually happens on VM

Comment: It looks like your big brother is watching your VM too. I hope you can implement Harry's suggestion but I don't know what self -administrative mode is. However it doesn't look that read-only ACL will help because it will (if will) prevent all changes but you need only proxy specific ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed likely you have encountered a Group Policy Preference (GPP), an optional part of the GPO system. These GPP are applied either on parameter change (on the side of the central admin) or on every regular GPO refresh - but between these, the end-user is free to change the values.

To check it, simply  create the GPO report. In an elevated command prompt, do `GPRESULT /H GPReport.html` and read the created HTML file. You will likely encounter the GPP parameter. Note the GPO name.

Now, since you do have (organisational) permission to change these parameters, the cleanest option is simply to nicely ask your admin to:

- first option: opt you out of the GPO. (give the GPO name and the GPO parameters to the admin)
- second option: make the GPP "apply on change" only.

If this is not possible, you may (if it has not been forbidden by another GPO...) disable regular refresh of GPOs. Just open local policies, go to  `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Group Policy` and set "Disable background refresh of Group Policy" to `enabled`. That way, GPO will only refresh on logon. Please note this may be seen as a security risk and be frowned upon by your administrator/security officer/whatever.

Comment: It doesn't look that GPP apply. It's Windows 7 not Windows server. Anyway I do not see any GPP mention in the html report. I see that GPO changes proxy settings and that's all. Thanks for answer anyway,

Comment: @Alex GPO (be it the old part or the recent GPP part) apply to both client and server machines. And the report does not explicitely say GPP. So I'm not sure I understand your comment - have you found a mention of the proxy settings in the report ?

Comment: Yes, I did. But under GPO header, not GPP. With your comment it makes sense. Now I'm back where I was - GPO changes registry for proxy whenever it wants and my process is broken. I guess there some way how to prevent particular registry from change but when I do it it takes default value which is GPO value and not what I need. Any ideas how I can prevent particular registry change?

Comment: The "Disable background refresh of Group Policy" Policy hasn't done the trick? Please note that a reboot is needed for it to be enforced.

Comment: To be honest I don't know how to do "Disable background refresh of Group Policy" but, I think, it will restrict whole GPO and our security team will be unhappy. I need to restrict couple fields, not entire GPO. Thanks for your efforts,